# Process Metrics in Springboot not coming

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I am facing a weird problem in spring boot application. I am exposing metrics through actuator and micrometer-registry-prometheus.

I am able to **see all expected metrics in when I run from my localhost** but **I am not able to see ProcessMetrics(cpuUsage, processUsage) when I deploy my application in my k8s** environment.

I have checked the version of the actuator and micrometer-prometheus as well, They are all same.

I have referred the link: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/513. The solution suggested did not work for me. **My service also contains Kafka and Postgres dependency.**

I dont know What is causing the issue. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: have you checked from metrics endpoint all the metrics you have? is it there?

Comment: check where? In k8s I checked on the "/prometheus" url it is not coming.

Comment: the `/metrics` endpoint?

Comment: I have not enabled it. Also, How does it matter? They are coming in my localhost on the prometheus endpoint and both of them have the same base right?

Comment: I'm thinking if prometheus endpoint only shows metrics that are enabled for prometheus metrics registry, but general metrics registry endpoint would show them all.

Comment: btw, is your k8s environment using one of supported jvm implementations? ( J9 or hotspot)